# Compare all files in two Directories using find command in sunOS

Tags: perl, hash, find

I am trying to traverse in two directories and compare each file and find the differences in them
The find command which iam using to save file names and the data using a perl hash  is apparantly  failaing
I am using SunS 5.10 ,
The code below would work on Linux OS

> Code Snippet that is failing

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my (%files1, %files2);
my ($dir1, $dir2) = @ARGV;
find( sub { -f && $files1{$_} = $File::Find::name }, $dir1);
find( sub { -f && $files2{$_} = $File::Find::name }, $dir2);
```

> Error

```
perl -c test_compare.pl
Can't modify logical and (&&) in scalar assignment at test_compare.pl line 9, near "$File::Find::name }"
test_compare.pl had compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [operator precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity), you could use `and` instead of `&&`:

```
find( sub { -f and $files1{$_} = $File::Find::name }, $dir1);
```